# Set time on label vb6 not the current time

Tags: vb6

I want to set a time like `2:00:00 PM` and run it by minutes. But I'm not getting the current time on my computer I just want to set a time when I entered a time in textbox and show it to the label then it will run and also the interval of my timer is equal to 1.

I tried this code but nothing happened. can anyone help me thank you

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

   timer1.enabled = true

End Sub


Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

   Label1.Caption = "2:00:00 PM"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "...not the current time"?  As the code stands, every time the timer fires, it's going to set the label caption to the exact same thing: "2:00:00 PM". Based on your code, why would you expect anything different?

Comment: You are setting the time to a constant string each time the timer ticks. Are you trolling us here? Try reading the documentation. Or perhaps [this helpful site](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/formating-dates-and-times-vb6).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you have set the interval property for the timer, unless you have set it in the properties.

If you add timer1.interval = 60000 above the timer1.enabled it should fire the timer event after 1 minute.

You can find some more information on it at [VB6 Timer interval property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235125(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial value of the Label1 caption in Form_Load(). Make sure the interval of the timer is set properly. In the Timer1_Timer() event, update the caption of Label1. To make sure you're showing the absolutely right value, you should not assume the timer fires perfectly at every interval. Instead, in Form_Load(), set a module level variable with current time. When the timer fires, get the difference between the current time (when timer fires) and the module level variable. Increment the initial value of the label ("2:00:00 PM" in the example you gave) by this difference and update the label to show that new value.